# HTML + JS - Trying to surround some content that is created with a for loop with a div

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding an adventure game and have a primitive `sortInventory()` function. It cycles through the `player.inventory` array and displays each item in its own `<div>`. I want to surround the entire completed 'inventory' with a `<div class="inv">` - here are the functions:

```
function sortInventory() {
  var rowCount = 0;
  var firstRowDone = false;

  for(var i = 0; i < player.inventory.length; i++) {
    rowCount++;
    if(rowCount == 6 && firstRowDone == false) {
      firstRowDone = true;
      rowCount = 0;
      dock.innerHTML += "<br>"
    }
    if(rowCount == 5 && firstRowDone) {
      dock.innerHTML += "<br>"
      rowCount = 0;
    }
    dock.innerHTML += "<div class='inv-item'><img class='inv-img' src='" + player.inventory[i].img + "'></img></div>";
  }
}

function showInventory() {
  dock.innerHTML = "<div class='inv'>";
  sortInventory();
  dock.innerHTML += "</div>"
}
```

This currently outputs:

```
<div class="inv"></div>
<div class="inv-item">..</div>
<div class="inv-item">..</div>
<!-- and so on -->
```

But I would like it to output:

```
<div class="inv">
    <div class="inv-item">..</div>
    <div class="inv-item">..</div>
    <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

How could I get it to achieve this and why does it close the tag early? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to write it in pieces, store it in a variable and write it all at once.

```
function sortInventory() {
  var rowCount = 0;
  var invList = '';

  for(var i = 0; i < player.inventory.length; i++) {
    rowCount++;
    if(rowCount == 6 && firstRowDone == false) {
      firstRowDone = true;
      rowCount = 0;
      dock.innerHTML += "<br>"
    }
    if(rowCount == 5 && firstRowDone) {
      dock.innerHTML += "<br>"
      rowCount = 0;
    }
    invList += "<div class='inv-item'><img class='inv-img' src='" + player.inventory[i].img + "'></img></div>";
  }
  return invList;
}

function showInventory() {
  dock.innerHTML = "<div class='inv'>" + sortInventory() + "</div>";      
}
```

This is happening because an open tag cannot live within the DOM without a close tag, with few exceptions like `<br />` which is still valid as `<br >`, so most browsers will try to compensate for this and write the close tag for you.

In short, writing incrementally into the innerHTML tag is always a bad idea and will lead to unexpected results as most all browsers will try to correct it.

Comment: Just for completeness you should add to the answer _why does it close the tag early?_, as the OP asked :)

Comment: This answer was very succinct and helped me figure out what I was doing wrong - I chose it as the answer as it was the first to help me solve the problem, but all answers that have been given are great!

Comment: @lealceldeiro if i remember correctly, its because an open tag cannot live within the DOM without a close tag, with few exceptions like `<br />` so most browsers will try to compensate for this and write the close tag for you. In short, writing incrementally into the innerHTML tag is always a bad idea and will lead to unexpected results as most all browsers will try to correct it.

Comment: thatguy, yes. I meant you should edit the answer for future readers. Some new users don't really read the comments :) @D.Winning, sure, you can [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) all answers you think are good for your question.

Answer (score 3):

Using `innerHTML` can be cumbersome, not to mention (at times) dangerous. Instead, I would use the `document.createElement` and `Node.appendChild` methods.

```
function sortInventory() {
  var rowCount = 0;

  var inv = document.createElement('div');
  inv.classList.add('inv');

  for(var i = 0; i < player.inventory.length; i++) {
    rowCount++;
    if(rowCount == 6 && firstRowDone == false) {
      firstRowDone = true;
      rowCount = 0;
      inv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
    if(rowCount == 5 && firstRowDone) {
      inv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
      rowCount = 0;
    }
    var invItem = document.createElement('div');
    invItem.classList.add('inv-item');

    var invImg = document.createElement('img');
    invImg.classList.add('inv-img');
    invImg.setAttribute('src', player.inventory[i].img);

    invItem.appendChild(invImg);
    inv.appendChild(invItem);
  }

  dock.appendChild(inv);
}

function showInventory() {
  sortInventory();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it closes the tag prematurely because the value received by [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) removes all of the element's descendants and replaces them with **nodes constructed** by parsing the HTML given in the string. With constructed nodes, it means (in this case) if there is any unclosed tag, it will close it first (so it is a constructed node).

So in order to solve this, first build the string, and finally use the `innerHTML` in order to set the built value.

Following your logic, it would be something like this:

```
var newHtml = "";
function sortInventory() {
  var rowCount = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < player.inventory.length; i++) {
    rowCount++;
    if(rowCount == 6 && firstRowDone == false) {
      firstRowDone = true;
      rowCount = 0;
      newHtml += "<br>"
    }
    if(rowCount == 5 && firstRowDone) {
      newHtml += "<br>"
      rowCount = 0;
    }
    newHtml += "<div class='inv-item'><img class='inv-img' src='" + player.inventory[i].img + "'></img></div>";
  }
}

function showInventory() {
  newHtml = "<div class='inv'>";
  sortInventory();
  newHtml += "</div>"
  dock.innerHTML = newHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a wrapper element with the class `.inv` around the elements with `.inv-item` classes, construct the HTML content at a string in the `sortInventory` function, then return as the `content` to use, when setting the `dock` element's `innerHTML`:

```js
var boxIcon = 'https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/122/122186.svg';
var player = {
  inventory: [
    {img: boxIcon},
    {img: boxIcon},
    {img: boxIcon}
  ]
};
var dock = document.getElementById('dock');

function sortInventory(inv) {
  var rowCount = 0;
  var content = ''

  for (var i = 0; i < player.inventory.length; i++) {
    rowCount++;
    if (rowCount == 6 && firstRowDone == false) {
      firstRowDone = true;
      rowCount = 0;
      content += "<br>"
    }
    if (rowCount == 5 && firstRowDone) {
      content += "<br>"
      rowCount = 0;
    }
    content += "<div class='inv-item'><img class='inv-img' width='32px' src='" + player.inventory[i].img + "'></img></div>";
  }
  
  return content;
}

function showInventory() {
  dock.innerHTML = "<div class='inv'>" + sortInventory() + "</div>";
}

showInventory();
```

```css
.inv {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="dock"></div>
```

[Credits to Flaticon](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/cube_122186)

Answer (score 0):

Construct the HTML string completely then assign to `innerHTML` of the `div`, instead of assigning `innerHTML` 3 times.

Change `sortInventory` function to return string, append all the string and assign it as `innerHTML` at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could first create the item with the class "inv" and then get it by class name with `document.getElementByClassName("inv")` and then add with a forloop `document.getElementByClassName("inv").innerHtml += <div class="inv-item">..<div>`